# How to check if a string is a float/int and not a NaN in Angular8?

Tags: angular, angular8

How to check if a string is a float/int and not a NaN in Angular8?

I couldn't find any answers relevant to Angular8

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript. So we can use JavaScript code in TypeScript with some slight modifications:

```
isIntOrFloat(n){
    return !isNaN(n);
}
```

Vanilla JavaScript version:

```js
function isIntOrFloat(n){
    return !isNaN(n);
}        
    
console.log(`is int 1? ${isIntOrFloat("1")}`)
console.log(`is int 1.5? ${isIntOrFloat("1.5")}`)
console.log(`is int a? ${isIntOrFloat('a')}`)
console.log(`is int b? ${isIntOrFloat('b')}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

As StepUp mentioned, typescript is a superset of javascript, you can use all javascript functionalities inside typescript.

```
const notNumber= (str) => isNaN(str)
```

notNumber(12)// returns false

notNumber("sd")// returns false